# MVC anchor tag and bootstrap model delete

Tags: jquery, html, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap

I'm developing an MVC 5 web application. Within one of my Razor Views I have a table which spits outs several rows of data. Beside each row of data is a Delete button. When the user clicks the delete button I want to have the Bootstrap Modal popup and ask the user to confirm their deletion.

```
  <table>
    <tr>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayName("Country")
        </th>
    </tr>

    @foreach (var item in Model)
    {
        <tr>

            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Country)
            </td>

            <td>
                @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "edit", new { id = item.ContactID }) |
                <a class="btn btn-danger btn-xs" data-id="@item.ContactID" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" id="delete"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></i></a>
            </td>
        </tr>
    }    
  </table>
```

As it is, when the user clicks the Delete button the Modal pops up fine, but I can't seem to get the ID in the anchor tag to pass to the Confirm button within my Modal so that it will then be sent to the delete action in my controller.

```
 <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-body">
                <input type="hidden" id="delete" />
                Are you sure you wish to delete this Customer?
            </div> 

            <div class="modal-footer">

                <button type="button" id="mySubmit" class="btn btn-danger">Ok</button>

                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

When I click the Delete button of bootstrap nothing happen and I cannot delete the record

Comment: Thanks @TZHX Please help me with my answer and I am new at MVC

Answer (score 0):

You can try as below:

```
$(document).on("click", ".btn-xs", function () {
     var Id = $(this).data('id');
     $(".modal-body #hdninput").val(Id);
});
```

Keep a hidden field in modal-body like this

```
<input type="hidden" id="hdninput"/>
```

> If you do have time go through **[Impromptu](http://trentrichardson.com/Impromptu/)** plugin

**EDIT:** To assign the particular id to your anchor tag or action link you can do as below:

**Assumptions** : Your modal, say `exampleModal` has a `actionlink/anchor tag` Delete in `modal-footer` whose Id is `btnDelete`

```
$('#exampleModal').on('show.bs.modal', function () {
  var hiddenID = $("#hdninput").val()
  var modal = $(this)
  modal.find('.modal-footer #btnDelete').attr('href','Customer/delete?id='+hiddenID); //This will attach the href to your actionlink or anchortag in modal.
});
```

**EDIT 2 -** Plus what I would suggest is to modify below part of code and remove `href` from that since you are now deleting once the user confirms and appending the `href` to the anchor which is present in modal.

```
<a href="~/Customer/delete" class="btn btn-danger btn-xs" data-id="@item.ContactID" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">
    <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></i> 
    Delete
</a>
```

to

```
<a class="btn btn-danger btn-xs" data-id="@item.ContactID" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">
    <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></i> 
    Delete
</a>
```

**EDIT 3 -**

```
$(document).on("click", ".btn-xs", function () {
      var Id = $(this).data('id');
      console.log(Id);//Check whether Id has been logged in your console.
      $(".modal-body #delete").val(Id);
      console.log($(".modal-body #delete").val())//check whether your hidden field has got the value ID
});
```

**Change the `button` in footer to `anchor` as below**

```
<a href="#" id="mySubmit" class="btn btn-danger">Ok</a>
```

The below code changes the href of your button in modal:

```
$('#myModal').on('show.bs.modal', function () {
      var hiddenID = $("#delete").val()
      var modal = $(this)
      modal.find('.modal-footer #mySubmit').attr('href','Customer/delete?id='+hiddenID); //This will attach the href to your actionlink or anchortag in modal.
    });
```

Comment: @ Guruprasad Rao ...what is the meaning of myBookId in here in reference to mine is it item.contactID or what if this is item.contactID then nothing happen just the same problem

Comment: Sorry for that!! I've edited the answer. It should have been `Id`

Comment: i have done that but nothing happen my modal-footer button doesnot fire any event

Comment: Check whether your input field hdninput is getting the value or not??

Comment: when i hover my mouse to the anchor tag it is not getting id which is to be delete it just only navigate to my controller with out passing it's id it just show the modal popup without getting the required id

Comment: What I would suggest it you need to add one more piece of code so that when your modal opens your anchor tag's url gets automatically set based on the hidden input field value!

Comment: oh i get the id to my anchor tag but couldnot pass that id to my bootstrap model pop example would be helpful

Comment: can we discuss this in chat i am little confused

Comment: sure... but I think you need minimum 20 reputation for that!!

Comment: sorry i haven't got reputation to chat 
i already told you sir i cannot pass id to the model of bootstrap in the hidden field my bootstrap model cannot get the id from the anchor tag

Comment: Ok. See here there are two things. **Modal** is different and **model** is different. So please be clear when you ask doubt. So just give me more details. Please post your complete modal code [edit your question] and I will edit that modal code in my answer.

Comment: please see the above edited question thankyou!  and the javascript is same as you posted
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('#myModal').on('show.bs.modal', function () {
        var hiddenID = $("#delete").val()
        var modal = $(this)
        modal.find('.modal-footer #mySubmit').attr('href','Customer/delete?id='+hiddenID);
    });
</script>

Comment: Add the above code mentioned in **EDIT 3** and check if you have any console errors.

Comment: i think hdninput is id but in my model i have not placed any hdninput so how does this work

Comment: By oversight I've forgot to change it.. Now I've edited my answer. Check it please. It should have been `delete` instead of `hdnInput`

Comment: @Guruprasad..Thanks for your help but i have solved that problem using bootbox